# How to save value of found document in mongoose as a variable?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

Let's say I use `findbyID{}` to find a specific document in my collection, and this document has the value `totalMedals` to which I want to add the local variable `medalsWonSinceLastUpdate`. I would need a function along the lines of `totalMedals = previousTotalMedals + medalsWonSinceLastUpdate`, which would mean I need to capture the previous `totalMedals` in a variable. How would this be possible?

---

I have experimented with an ejs file that contains the value I want to access and then tried to access it through req.body.value, but this throws an error. I can run  queries that find the documents, but I run into a brick wall when it comes to taking the variables to a wider scope.